# What is the origin and meaning of the expression "going doolally"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

Today I came across the expression "going doolally" which was aimed at an individual and I suspect it is uncomplimentary. From where did the expression originate and what does it mean?

Comment: Where did you come across it? What research did you do? (A simple Google search turns up several answers to this question.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - I realise Google is a useful source of information, but I prefer to go to Stack Exchange sites to find answers to questions. I have also observed a noticeable drop in activity on at least two Stack Exchange sites I frequent. I wonder why that is?

Comment: I can't comment on other SE sites, but this one [asks you to do research before asking questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Just Googling, I couldn't find much, myself. Gio's answer is a good one, but I would not have found that myself, I have to confess. It is not helpful to censure people who have only had a little experience on EL&U. Perhaps a little kindness would not hurt too much, I suggest ? (Yes, we all know the 'rules'.)

Comment: @NigelJ When searching "going doolally" in Google, the first line is a definition apparently provided by Google, the first search result is a page from Quora titled "What does the British expression 'go doolally' mean?", the second is a definition from Collins Dictionary, the third is a definition from The Free Dictionary, the fourth is this page, the fifth is a definition from Oxford Learner's Dictionaries, etc. Sorry, but I think that it is **very** easy to find answers to this question online.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan But since the OP has asked the question we now have the information in the EL&U _archive_ . (Which is the purpose of the site - to provide an archive of research.)

Comment: @NigelJ My first comment was written before any of the answers. I'm not suggesting deleting any answers.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan . . . . .  and, with that, we are in agreement. (As are the up-voters of both the question and the answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression is of military origin and it refers to a specific place in India:

***[doolally](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/paamxuq)*** adj.
(also doolaley, do-lally)

> [the Deolalie milit. sanatorium in Bombay, to which mentally ill troops were sent. However, according to the veteran Frank Richards, writing in his memoir Old Soldier Sahib (1936), the illness came not before one arrived at Deolalie but during one’s stay there. Time-expired troops were sent to the sanatorium to await the next troop-ship home. It was during the long hot days of tedium that men, formerly first-class soldiers, might gradually go to pieces]
> (orig. milit.)
>
> 1. mad, eccentric; thus used as noun a madman (see cite 1914) or madness (see cite 2019); occas as n. see cite 1994.

> - 1902    [UK]    Sheffield Eve. Teleg. 27 Oct. 10/1: Prisoner said when he got a drop of beer he became ‘doolally’.
> - 1914    [UK]    Burnley News 14 Nov. 2/4: He was what the soldiers called a ‘doolally’: immediately he got drunk he got mad.

(GDoS)

Answer (score 3):

[Doolally:](https://www.turnerink.co.uk/word-stuff/indian-words-in-everyday-use/)

From the town of Deolali, the location of an army base and sanatorium where soldiers leaving India in the late 19th century were sent before leaving for home. Those that became mentally deranged after contacting a fever, or Tap in Urdu, were said to have gone Doolally Tap.

Comment: That’s the first time I’ve seen ‘doolally tap’ used outside of the West Midlands.